# Passing an array to a route NodeJS Express

Tags: html, node.js, express

I am trying to pass an array of objects to a view with 
**res,render("landing.ejs", {logos: logos}**
 method. 
I have the array declared in my app.js and when my view loads it works perfectly with:

```
    <% logos.forEach(function(logo){ %>
        <div class="col-5 imgContainer my-auto pt-4">
            <a href="<%= logo.url %>" target="_blank">
                <img class="logo" src="<%= logo.image %>" title="<%= logo.title %>" alt="<%= logo.title %>">
            </a>
        </div>
     <% }) %>
```

But when I deploy my app onto my server I get the error saying that logo has not been defined. I've tried moving my var logos array outside of my get route but it still doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    fs = require('fs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    var logos = [

        {
            image: '/images/logos/a_html5.png',
            title: "html",
            url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5"
        },
        {
            image: '/images/logos/b_css3.png',
            title: "CSS3",
            url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#CSS_3"
        },
        {
            image: '/images/logos/c_JS.png',
            title: "JavaScript",
            url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript"
        },
        {
            image: '/images/logos/d_sass.png',
            title: "Sass",
            url: "https://sass-lang.com/"
        },
        {
            image: '/images/logos/e_NodeJS.jpg',
            title: "Node JS",
            url: "https://nodejs.org/en/"
        },
        {
            image: '/images/logos/f_express.png',
            title: "express",
            url: "https://expressjs.com/"
        },
        {
            image: '/images/logos/g_semantic.png',
            title: "Semantic UI",
            url: "https://semantic-ui.com/"
        },
        {
            image: '/images/logos/h_bootstrap.png',
            title: "Bootstrap",
            url: "https://getbootstrap.com/"
        },
        {
            image: '/images/logos/i_git.png',
            title: "Git",
            url: "https://git-scm.com/"
        },
        {
            image: '/images/logos/j_mongoDB.png',
            title: "mongo DB",
            url: "https://www.mongodb.com/"
        }

    ];

    res.render("landing", { logos: logos });
});




app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
    console.log("server is running");
});
```

Comment: Can you add your server-side code, please?

Comment: Hm, this actually looks ok (apart from using `var` instead of `const/let` :)). Could you also add the exact error message?

Comment: I've managed to fix it! Thanks for your help/time anyway!